# PHP Composer: how to load and use a plugin located outside of vendor/?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

Is there a way to make Composer run an installer plugin located in `./src/`?

The [relevant docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/plugins.md) are rather unclear as to how it should be done, assuming it's possible to begin with.

If not, the docs also seem to suggest that it's possible to install a plugin in COMPOSER_HOME, but say essentially nothing as to *how* this can be done — any pointers would be most welcome.

Just to clarify: the problem isn't about autoloading the class as much as it is making composer load the plugin when running `composer install` or `composer update`.

My project setup:

```
./app
…
./src
./src/Hello
./src/Hello/HelloPlugin.php
./vendor
…
```

The plugin file:

```
<?php # ./src/Hello/Hello.php
namespace Hello;

use Composer\Composer;
use Composer\IO\IOInterface;
use Composer\Plugin\PluginInterface;

class HelloPlugin implements PluginInterface
{
    public function activate(Composer $composer, IOInterface $io);
    {
        echo "Hello World!".PHP_EOL;
    }
} # END class
```

The relevant lines of the project's `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "hello/world",
    "type": "project",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Hello\\": "src/"
         }
    },
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "~1.0",
        "composer-plugin-api": "~1.0"
    },
    "extra": {
        "class": ["Hello\\HelloPlugin"]
    }
}
```

Comment: You're mixing up psr-4 and psr-0 :)

Comment: @Jack: fixed and question edited, but the problem isn't about autoloading the class… It is about making composer load the plugin when running `composer install` or `composer update`.

Comment: The way I understand it is that you have to create a separate package for your plugin with `"type": "composer-plugin"`.

Comment: Ya, vendoring it works indeed, and I eventually resorted to that. I'm still curious to know if it's possible, if the case ever arises where I don't want to (or cannot) vendor an installer plugin because e.g. it's not a library.

Answer (score 1):

The composer `autoload` is used to load all the `namespaces` of packages you `require` in you project and it is not intended to load plugins during the `composer install` or `composer update` hook.

The only way to load your own plugin class, is to implement your own composer plugin, a normal package of type `composer-plugin`, which will be used by composer to load your `HelloPlugin` class. Otherwise, your plugin class will not be loaded during the `composer install` hook.

I have built a `composer-plugin` myself, here you can find it https://github.com/mnsami/composer-custom-directory-installer , for references.

And if you have more questions/or help, please don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score -1):

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Hello\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: Changed that, but still not loading the plugin when I run `composer install` or `composer update` I'm afraid. :-(